# Eclipse JDT: AST or SearchEngine

Tags: java, parsing, search, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm developing a tool to detect accessibility defects in Android applications by parsing the source code.

To parse the XML UI layouts of the app I'm using Java's SAX XML parser. This gives me access to the individual elements and its attributes, and I check their values if it meets the accessibility criteria. However, an UI element can also be modified from its associated Java class. Hence I also need to check the Java class if it's adding attributes to the UI element on start up to get accurate results.

Eg snippet of code I will be looking for in Java class:

```
EditText mContentEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.content);
mContentEditText.setContentDescription("An edit text box");
```

I'm planning to use the Eclipse's JDT core API to check Java source code. But, my question is should I create an Abstract Syntax Tree first, and then verify the code or use the SearchEngine feature to search for local variable declarations and method invocations as mentioned in the eg.
How should I proceed?